# Android: How to download file and show notification with progressbar?

Tags: android, asynchronous, notifications, progress-bar

I have an activity that downloads a file from the web when a button is clicked. The downloading of the file is done via an inner AsyncTask. The download works, I can even show, update, and hide a progressbar widget in the the Activitys layout.xml using the AsyncTask. I can also, show a notification from this AsyncTask. I Cannot however, update the progressbar inside the notification from the AsyncTask. I get a Force Close as soon as the first update is processed. Will supply my code if needed!

Thanks for your time

```
InvocationTargetException.<init>(Throwable) line: 50    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not              available [native method] 
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 845  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 603 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

This is thrown to this line

```
myContentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, Integer.parseInt(progress[0]), false);
```

Here is my code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
String path = url.getPath();
String filename = new File(path).getName();
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File tm = new File("/sdcard/Transform Mii/");
tm.mkdirs();
File out = new File(tm, filename);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(out);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
progressbar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
myContentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, Integer.parseInt(progress[0]), false);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
}
```

progressbar is the bar that is in the activity's layout.xml, this updates normally

myContentView progressbar is the bar that is inside the notification

Comment: The stack trace would be great.

Comment: What error do you get? Check the logcat.

Comment: Do you update the progressbar widget from onProgressUpdate() method? There can be errors when updating from doInBackground() as this method is executed in different thread, while onProgressUpdate() is executed in the UI thread.

Comment: @ruslan yes the updating is done via onProgressUpdate. Thank you anyhow

Comment: post some code, your onProgressUpdate method and the part in doInBackground that calls it.

Comment: Wow... I can also and  I Cannot however